# HTML5 JQM Table Issue

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, html-table

When I use data-role="table" my table goes to two columns and the table headers repeat themselves on the far left column. I want the headers to stay in one row at the top, as a table header should be. What do I need to fix?

On the left is what I want it to look like with the JQM formatting, which is what the right is but I don't know why it is being so weird.

[image]

Code:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-inline="true">
                <h4>Hole Info</h4>
                <table data-role="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>Rating/Slope</td>
                            <td>Hole 1</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>                   
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Blue</td>
                            <td>70.1/121</td>
                            <td>420 yds</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>White</td>
                            <td>68.7/119</td>
                            <td>395 yds</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Green</td>
                            <td>67.0/113</td>
                            <td>370 yds</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Par</td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>4</td>                                
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>Handicap</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Red</td>
                            <td>68.0/112</td>
                            <td>290 yds</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Par</td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>4</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Can you post (or link to) a screenshot of the issue, as well as any custom CSS that applies to the table? Have you tried switching to column-toggle mode and see if the problem persists?

Comment: column-toggle makes it look like the left picture. There is no css on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class="ui-responsive" to use the default breakpoints for reflow and change the cells in the thead to th instead of tr elements:

```
<table data-role="table" data-mode="reflow" class="ui-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <th>Rating/Slope</th>
            <th>Hole 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gz0xfqac/)**

UPDATE:

To get rid of the reflow entirely:

```
<table data-role="table" data-mode="">
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gz0xfqac/3/)**

Comment: The issue still stands with all of that. Your jsfiddle even has the issue.

Comment: @justin, only if you resize the pane to be small. If you make the output pane wider in the fiddle you will see that the table automatically changes between the 2 views as it is designed to do. If you want always the column view, set data-mode="": See my updated answer.